# How to background another process in Python?

Tags: python

The thing is, I'm trying to get a process inside my script and have me call it whenever I want. For example, I'm filling in some data and I enter the word "background". In this way, it is called a process that is always active. I leave my code in python, I have created a decorator but I get the following error: "EOFError".

Besides that, it should work both ways, when I'm in the background and insert "background", it should return to the main function.

I share with you the code I've been doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os, time

def daemonLife(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if os.fork(): return
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        os._exit(os.EX_OK)
    return wrapper

@daemonLife
def my_func():
   no_kill_nothing = "Hi!"
   print('pid of it: %d' % os.getppid())
   var2 = str(input("Inside of background!"))
   if var2 == "background":
      main(no_kill_nothing)

def main(text):
   if text == "background":
      my_func()

text = str(input("Insert something"))
main(text)
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why don't you use the multiprocessing module?

Comment: I really tried but it didn't work, so I decided to use a decorator I created @Barmar

Comment: Where do you get this `EOFError`?

Comment: I insert the first "background" and then enter the function "my_func" but when trying to write "background" appears "EOFERROR".

Comment: @mapsiyadru: That’s not precise enough—you need to edit the whole traceback into your question and explain exactly what has been entered on the terminal.  (You also need to “@“mention people when replying.)